# iOS 7 Completion handler never gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios-simulator, completionhandler

In the following code none of the completion handlers ever get executed. The one explanation I was able to find is this [Bug in iPhone Simulator 5.1 with Xcode 4.5 using UIManagedDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557442/bug-in-iphone-simulator-5-1-with-xcode-4-5-using-uimanageddocument) . It says that it might be a bug in iPhone simulator 5.1 . However, I've tried iPhone simulators 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0, none of them worked. I'll really appreciate your help.

(By the way, I've seen this code in the Stanford iOS course, lecture 14)

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataDocument"];
UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){

        NSLog(@"This logs");

    [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){

        NSLog(@"This never logs");

    }];

}else if(document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){

        NSLog(@"This logs");
    [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        NSLog(@"This never logs");
    }];

}else{
    //I have a separate log for this, but it's never 'else'
}
```

EDIT: I've found a question that seems to be dealing with exactly the same problem. [I Can't get an nsmanageobjectcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939352/i-cant-get-an-nsmanageobjectcontext?rq=1) I just pinned it down to the completion handler not being executed.

EDIT: I found out what the problem was: because openWithCompletionHandler executes asynchronously, my app would try to use the document before it finished opening. Using a run loop solved the problem. Example below.

```
if(doc.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){

    NSLog(@"This logs");
    __block BOOL waitingOnCompletionHandler = YES;
    [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){

        NSLog(@"This logs too!");

    }];

    while (waitingOnCompletionHandler) {
       NSDate *futureTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:futureTime];
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried it on a real device?

Comment: I don't have a real device :/

Comment: What debugging did you do to check the code is called?

Comment: You code is fine. I have copy/paste you code in Xcode and it's working fine with simulator 5.0, 6 and 7. i am using Xcode 5.0.1.

Comment: Good bet: `document` is nil, log that it is or not nil.

Comment: Does the document exist? NSLog the path and check it.

Comment: I've just checked, the document exists.

Comment: Wain, I used logs and breakpoints